# How to extract data from a json object which contains a map with different kinds of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I return JSON from a server which is a JSONified Map object from java. 
The Map has a list and an integer. How can I get the list in jquery?

```
int found = hits.length;

List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();

for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits) {
     ....
     // create an object and add to results list
     results.add(Object)
}

Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("results", results);
map.put("hits", found);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

I pull the results from search by ajax:

```
function  search(query){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'search',
        data: query,
        success: function(data){
            showResults(data);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Now in show results i dont know how to get my List from the map. any help will be greatly appreciated

```
function showResults(data){
    if(!$('#liveSearchContainer').is(':visible')){
        $(this).show(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `data` variable (in the success callback) contain? From the Java code it looks like you could do something like `data.results` to access the list of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some facts about javascript and JQuery

- jQuery should parse the data for you from a JSON string to javascript objects.
- All javascript objects are effectively hash maps
- You can access javascript object properties by doing `object.someProperty` or `object["someProperty"]`
- If you are unsure what has been passed to a function, do `console.log(arguments)`

Answer:

in function `showResults`:

```
var results = data.results
// Hash lookups are so quick that the only reason
// we cache the result is so we have less to type!
```

Then something like

```
$('#liveSearchContainer').html('<p>'+data.hits+' hits</p><ol></ol>');

results.forEach(function(result) {
  $('#liveSearchContainer ol').append(buildResultHTML(result));
})

// Where you might write buildResultHTML to build HTML for a search result
```